# Serving index page with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've looked all over and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with the way I am trying to serve my `index.html` page in my packaged spring-boot jar file. This is my app structure:

[image: package structure]

When I run `mvn clean install` it packages the jar properly and actually puts the `index.html` file into the static folder in the jar.

Here is my MVC Conf:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
}
```

Anything I am not doing properly?

Comment: The static folder resource handler is provided out of the box by Spring Boot.  Try removing the customization you provided and running the application again.  Your page should be accessible from localhost:8080/index.html  If you're still having trouble, share some more detail such as the HTTP Response and any Java Errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not getting any Java errors or HTTP errors (besides the 404). Is there any other configuration required to serve pages? I got rid of my custom resource handler but that did nothing unfortunately :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I fixed it thanks to help from multiple sources! Here is what I did so it may help someone else:

1) add this resource in the POM. I am still not sure why I need this but my app will not serve without this. Spring boot **should** be doing this automatically but it apparently was not.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/static</directory>
        <targetPath>static</targetPath>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

2) In my MVC configuration I added this (similar to the answer below):

```
    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
```

after adding these two things, my app started serving files!

Comment: Glad you got it working for yourself.  I believe something else is going on since this should work out of the box.  If you're still curious, post a link to a GitHub repo that reproduces this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "classpath" to the resource location,

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should read this, how to serve static content:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

To sum it up, your browser is caching your static resources, such as CSS files or html files.

In order to break this behavior, try first clean your browser cache, in google chrome you go to settings then clear browsing data.

Secondly, add these lines to your application.properties file in order to bust the cache:

```
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

or add this instead:

```
spring.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.paths=/**
spring.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.version=v12
```

Answer (score 0):

On spring boot project, you can get this working just by extending **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** and override **addResourceHandlers** as below

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        }   
    }
```

The index page will be accessible on http://localhost:8080/static/index.html